# upload to onedrive from device / embedded system

Tags: onedrive

want to upload files to onedrive from embedded Linux. No browser. So OAuth 2.0 authorization flow does not work - can't display the consent screen etc.

Google API has a device flow... But it's not available for google drive.

Is there similar flow (in the work) for onedrive? Any workaround for now?

Comment: Did you explore ways of getting OAuth token without displaying the consent screen?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get an access token from another device with a screen, like a smart phone, share this access token to the embedded Linux device, then it can upload the file to OneDrive, but you need to make sure the access token is valid in that period.